Accepted a job offer, but now want to negotiate salary
I work in the United States. I have actively been interviewing for the past month. Some interviews went well, while some did not so well. I also received several rejections to my resume and never had an interview with many places where I sent my resume. At that point, my self-esteem and morale were low. Two days ago, I received a call from a company with a job offer for a position I wanted. The work hours are great, and it is 100% remote. I was so happy to hear from someone with an offer and excited to accept it immediately. I was not even thinking about pay. I remember feeling so happy I was chosen from all the applicants.
Two days later, I saw that I had accepted a job paying $7 less than the position I was leaving, and I felt like I was undervaluing myself. I have several years of work experience. I do not start the job until June 3rd. There is a long onboarding process. So, I have not officially started yet. I want to contact the recruiter or hiring manager to ask if the pay amount is negotiable and say that I hastily accepted the offer without considering the salary. My question is, would they entertain my wish to negotiate salary after I have accepted the position? My motives are that I lowballed myself unintentionally.
I called the hiring manager, who told me I would receive an additional $3.00 night differential. And a $3.50 weekend differential. This was supposed to be outlined in the offer letter, but it was not. I told her the differential terms were not in the letter. She said she told the recruiter to put these terms in the letter. She apologized. I was more accepting of these terms and thanked her for clarifying. So I hung up feeling more confident since I spoke up, and now I know I will receive more pay since I will be working an overnight shift.

UPDATE: I called the hiring manager and she explained to me that there is an additional $3.00 night differential that I will receive. And a $3.50 weekend differential. This was supposed to be outlined in the offer letter, but it was not. I told her the differential terms was not in the letter. She said she told the recruiter to put these terms in the letter. She apologized. I was more accepting of these terms and thanked her for clarifying. So I hung up feeling more confident since I spoke up and now know I will be receiving more pay since I will be working an overnight shift.

@DiligentWorker25 - Why is that information in a comment instead of your question?

I have added this to the question.


My question is would they entertain my wish to negotiate salary after
I have accepted the position? My motives are that I low-balled myself
unintentionally.

Due to lack of crystal ball (budget deficits) no one can really say for your specific situation.
Generally, this would be seen in a bad light, probably not as bad as a red flag, but definitely deep yellow because renegotiating after signing a contract is... well, it's not what organised and put together people do usually.
That can mean that they will happily revisit with you, outright cancel the contract or anything in between. Decide yourself if that's worth the risk. And for the future remember: there's nothing wrong with saying "I want to wait a day to have a think about it" before signing a contract.

Well, at least you know what you need to work on improving. Personally, at this point I would either break the agreement and look elsewhere. Or accept it and talk to management about what they need to see from you to justify a raise. Trying to split the difference seems unlikely to work out well for you.

You will have to be prepared to walk away from the job if you have accepted the job and attempt to negotiate after the fact.
